# How do I autofill an array formula until the output is 0

Tags: vba, excel

How would I fill down an array formula until the formula starts outputting 0?

I have a lookup formula like this:

```
=OFFSET(RawData!$A$1,SMALL(IF(RawDataStatusType="Application Approved",ROW(RawDataStatusType)-1,100000),ROW($B3)-2),0)
```

and I'm wondering how I can use VBA to automate filling this down until it starts outputting 0?

Comment: Use a Do Until and Evaluate.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know if that was the best way or not!